# Retrieve audio samples from javax.sound.sampled.Clip

Tags: java, audio, javasound

I have an audio clip created by the following. Now I'd like to edit the audio samples in this clip. How do I read and write audio samples from and to this clip?

```
    AudioInputStream sound = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(soundFile);
    DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(Clip.class, sound.getFormat());
    clip = (Clip) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
    clip.open(sound);
```

Answer (score 1):

`Clip` is a convenience class for playing sounds that is not intended for anything more complex (so it will not provide the `AudioInputStream` for further processing).

It will be necessary to get the audio frames directly from the `AudioInputStream` before it is passed to the `Clip`.  At that stage, write the altered frames to an `AudioOutputStream` wrapped in a `ByteArrayOutputStream`.  Then use the BAOS to establish a new, altered, `AudioInputStream`.

Sound complicated?  And that is before even touching on altering the audio bytes.  Left as an exercise for the reader.  ;)